# Oracle : Error in Declare

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to execute the following query in PL/SQL developer:

```
DECLARE 
 P_FILENAME VARCHAR2(200):= 'file1.csv';
 P_DIRECTORY VARCHAR2(200):= 'ORA_DIR';
 P_IGNORE_HEADERLINES NUMBER := 1;

BEGIN
 Load_file( P_FILENAME => P_FILENAME, P_DIRECTORY => P_DIRECTORY, P_IGNORE_HEADERLINES =>     P_IGNORE_HEADERLINES );
END
```

I get the error :

```
ORA-06550: line 9, column 0:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
; <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
The symbol ";" was substituted for "end-of-file" to continue.
```

Where am I going wrong here.

Comment: i am no oracle, i can not see any picture.now, it looks fine after edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are missing a semi colon on the `end` statement:

```
DECLARE 
 P_FILENAME VARCHAR2(200):= 'file1.csv';
 P_DIRECTORY VARCHAR2(200):= 'ORA_DIR';
 P_IGNORE_HEADERLINES NUMBER := 1;

BEGIN
 Load_file( P_FILENAME => P_FILENAME, P_DIRECTORY => P_DIRECTORY, 
           P_IGNORE_HEADERLINES =>     P_IGNORE_HEADERLINES );
END;
/
```